# Generate Kusto Equivalent to Row_Rank()

Tags: pyspark

How can I generate this expected output?

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([
    ['SEA', 'LH', 3, 2],
    ['SEA', 'LY', 100, 3],
    ['SEA', 'UA', 3, 2],
    ['SEA', 'BA', 2, 1],
    ['SEA', 'EL', 3, 2],
]),
                           ['Airport', 'Airline', 'Departures', 'Expected'])

order_col = F.col('Departures').asc()

windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy("Departures").orderBy(order_col)
df.withColumn("row_number", F.dense_rank().over(windowSpec)).show()
```

```
+-------+-------+----------+--------+----------+
|Airport|Airline|Departures|Expected|row_number|
+-------+-------+----------+--------+----------+
|    SEA|     BA|         2|       1|         1|
|    SEA|     EL|         3|       2|         1|
|    SEA|     UA|         3|       2|         2|
|    SEA|     LH|         3|       2|         3|
|    SEA|     LY|       100|       3|         1|
+-------+-------+----------+--------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer as so:

```
windowSpec = Window.orderBy(F.asc("Departures"))
df = df.withColumn("row_number", F.dense_rank().over(windowSpec))
df.show()
```